# Retrieve endpoint for active service bus trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Given the following topic trigger:

```
        [FunctionName("eventhandler")]
        public static Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("domain.event", "domain.subscription", Connection = "QueueConnection")]
                               BrokeredMessage mySbMsg,
                               IBinder binder,
                               TraceWriter traceWriter,
                               CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

How can i retrieve the full endpoint of the Service Bus Trigger without needing to add additional custom settings in application config? Is there any environment variables i can retrieve within the run function?

Answer (score 0):

To get an environment variable or an app setting value, use System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable.

```
public static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name)
{
    return name + ": " +
        System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#environment-variables

Comment: Hm. I'll see if i can find the configuration inside environment variables.

Comment: The environment variables only really has the queue connection string that's in use. I could parse this of course but it's not ideal.